# WPF. Наложение своих окон на окна чужих программ.

Tags: c#, wpf, gui

Какими методами можно реализовать что-то подобное?
[image]

Comment: На рисунке, скорее всего, не наложение окон, а наложение контролов.

Comment: Я не правильно выразился, глупо вышло. Примерно в какой области нужно танцевать, чтобы добиться похожего эффекта?

Comment: Зависит от того, чего именно вам хочется.

1. Посмотрите на [`Popup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), скорее всего вам нужно именно это.
2. Ещё вариант -- организовать `Canvas` поверх основного контента, и добавлять элементы в нужные места. Тут возникнет проблема, если юзер поменяет размер окна приложения: вам придётся делать layout management вручную.

Answer (score 1):

Я подобное делал с помощью Grid'ов. мне надо было на фоне основного пользовательского интерфейса вывести сообщение о выполнении операции. Получилось как-то так:

```
  <Grid>
      <Grid>
        <!--Тут основные контролы-->
         ...
      <Grid>
      <Border>
         <!--Тут я выводил сообщение-->
         ...
      </Border>
   </Grid>
```

Вместо Border можно положить еще один Grid и уже в него укладывать то что Вам нужно "сверху".